# How to Distinct on particular column in JPA (Criteria Builder)

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I have written JPA code for Distinct in inner query, below is my JPA code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager_gbl.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<sourceTracking> cq = cb.createQuery(sourceTracking.class);
Root<sourceTracking> data1 = cq.from(sourceTracking.class);
Subquery<String> subq=cq.subquery(String.class);
Root<sourceTracking> sbf=subq.from(sourceTracking.class);
subq.select(sbf.<String>get("message_id")).distinct(true);
cq.where(data1.<String>get("tablekey").in(subq));
cq.select(data1);
```

This code is generating SQL query is

```
select * 
from source_tracking 
where tablekey in (select distinct message_id from source_tracking )
```

But my requirement is here, distinct is applied to message_id, but fetching tablekey.

```
select * 
from source_tracking 
where tablekey in (select distinct on (message_id) tablekey 
                   from source_tracking)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you will not be able to use proprietary features like `distinct on()` with your obfuscation layer. But why can't you simply use `where tablekey in (select tablekey from source_tracking)` there is no need to apply a distinct to a query used for an `IN` condition.

Comment: thanks for reply but message_id has duplicate values so i want to fetch table key of distinct message id.is there any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: That's exactly the point of a_horse. This condition is in the WHERE which means that you don't need to worry about it having duplicates. `where somefild in (1, 1)` has absolutely no difference to `where somefild in (1)` It will even be more performatic.

Comment: `distinct` in the sub-select for an `IN` condition is completely useless. The `IN` operator will only consider distinct values anyway.

Comment: actually messageid is duplicate and tablekey is unque, if in subquery fetch unique messageid but in outer query fetch duplicate messageid.my requirement is have to fetch  all values of unique messageid.